# After upgrading angular from 5.1 to 8, flex-layout have few errors

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout, ng-upgrade

[Flex-layout-error-log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4x3eZ.png)

below is my package.json with all the dependencies, i have a flex-layout version 8.0.0-beta.26, please suggest a way or work around for this

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "8.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "8.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "8.1.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "8.0.0-beta.26",
    "@angular/forms": "8.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "8.1.0",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-angular": "^3.1.0",
    "classlist-polyfill": "^1.2.0",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "3.1.4",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "rxjs": "6.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2",
    "tinymce": "5.0.9",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  }
```

Comment: did you update `@angular/flex-layout` ? show your current `package.json` please.

Comment: i have pasted , please check

Comment: i think one of the problems is related to [this change](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-4)